# Kubernetes (on-premises) Metallb LoadBalancer and sticky sessions

Tags: kubernetes, internal-load-balancer, sticky-session, metallb

I installed one Kubernetes Master and two kubernetes worker on-premises.

After I installed Metallb as LoadBalancer using commands below:

```
$ kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy 
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1 
kind: KubeProxy
Configuration mode:
"ipvs" ipvs:
   strictARP: true

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.6/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.9.6/manifests/metallb.yaml
kubectl create secret generic -n metallb-system memberlist --from-literal=secretkey="$(openssl rand -base64 128)"

vim config-map.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.100.170.200-10.100.170.220

kubectl apply -f config-map.yaml
kubectl describe configmap config -n metallb-system
```

I created my yaml file as below:

**myapp-tst-deploy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-tst-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp-tst
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-tst
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-tst
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-tst
        image: myapp-tomcat
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          capabilities:
            add:
              - SYS_ADMIN
```

**myapp-tst-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-tst-service
  labels:
    app: myapp-tst
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: myapp-tst-port
    nodePort: 30080
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp-tst
  sessionAffinity: None
```

**myapp-tst-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-tst-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "INGRESSCOOKIE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
spec:
  rules: 
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: myapp-tst-service
              servicePort: myapp-tst-port
```

I run `kubectl -f apply` for all three files, and these is my result:

```
kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/myapp-tst-deployment-54474cd74-p8cxk   1/1     Running   0          4m53s   10.36.0.1   bcc-tst-docker02   <none>           <none>
pod/myapp-tst-deployment-54474cd74-pwlr8   1/1     Running   0          4m53s   10.44.0.2   bca-tst-docker01   <none>           <none>

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE     SELECTOR
service/myapp-tst-service   LoadBalancer   10.110.184.237   10.100.170.15   80:30080/TCP   4m48s   app=myapp-tst,tier=backend
service/kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>          443/TCP        6d22h   <none>

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                  SELECTOR
deployment.apps/myapp-tst-deployment   2/2     2            2           4m53s   myapp-tst      mferraramiki/myapp-test   app=myapp-tst

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                  SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/myapp-tst-deployment-54474cd74   2         2         2       4m53s   myapp-tst      myapp/myapp-test   app=myapp-tst,pod-template-hash=54474cd74
```

But when I try to connect using LB external IP (10.100.170.15) the system redirect the browser request
(on the same browser) on a pod, if I refresh or open a new tab (on the same url) the system reply redirect the request to another pod.

I need when a user digit url in the browser, he must be connect to a specific pod during all session, and not switch to other pods.

How can solve this problem if is it possible?
In my VM I resolved this issue using stickysession, how can enable it on LB or in Kubernetes components?

Comment: metallb on its own provides Load balancing but does not handle Ingress resources. Did you install something which manage the Ingress? Right now you are creating an Ingress but then you are actually using the LoadBalancer IP of your app directly which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Marco Ferrara could you verify if you are getting the cookie in your browser? because your error is very clear, you assigned the load balancer to the local service and not to the ingress controller service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the myapp-tst-service.yaml file the "sessionAffinity" is set to "None".

You should try to set it to "ClientIP".

From page https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ :

"If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity based on the client's IP addresses by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP" (the default is "None"). You can also set the maximum session sticky time by setting service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP.timeoutSeconds appropriately. (the default value is 10800, which works out to be 3 hours)."